# How to convert ASCII file to TIN where XY is YX in ArcGIS?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, tin, ascii, xyz

I have some ASCII files (you can download it from: http://analizasan.kvprojekty.pl/underwork/gisse/M3451Ca1.zip) that I would like to create TIN.

First I used "ASCII3DToFeatureClass" tool to create shapefiles with points. Then "CreateTin" tool to create TIN. Everything is fine but my XY coordinates are reversed and my TIN is somewhere else compared to the real.

Can I indicate X and Y when I create TIN by "CreateTin" tool? I know that I can edit .asc file in TXT Editor but it is a lot of work.

These files are in PUWG_1992 coordinate system (Poland):
Projection: Gauss_Kruger
False_Easting: 500000,0
False_Northing: -5300000,0
Central_Meridian: 19,0
Scale_Factor: 0,9993
Latitude_Of_Origin: 0,0
Linear Unit: Meter (1,0)

Geographic Coordinate System: GCS_ETRS_1989
Angular Unit: Degree (0,0174532925199433)
Prime Meridian: Greenwich (0,0)
Datum: D_ETRS_1989
  Spheroid: GRS_1980
    Semimajor Axis: 6378137,0
    Semiminor Axis: 6356752,314140356
    Inverse Flattening: 298,257222101

I'm waiting for help.

Answer (score 1):

Export your shapefile somewhere. Remove prj file. Open this file in new ArcGIS session. Make sure dataframe does not have projection defined. Run this script on Shape field:

```
def SwapXY(shp):
 fp=shp.firstPoint
 point=arcpy.Point(fp.Y,fp.X,fp.Z)
 return point
```

Expression:

```
SwapXY(!Shape!)
```

alternatively run Add Geometry Attributes (Data Management)  on shapefile.
Export table to Excel and bring it back as XY Excel table

Comment: I don't know why but density of points is smaller and TIN is less detailed after expression.